# nodejs active on boot with nvm $HOME/nvm/nvm.sh

Tags: node.js, nvm

I installed node with nvm it works fine, but every new session i need to do `source $HOME/nvm/nvm.sh` to get node active

How can I do to be active on boot so there is no need to type `source $HOME/nvm/nvm.sh` in every sssh session

I try to add this command `source $HOME/nvm/nvm.sh` to `/etc/rc.local` but I get the following error

```
>  /etc/init.d/node_start.sh: 13: root/nvm/nvm.sh: Bad substitution
>     /etc/init.d/node_start.sh: 78: root/nvm/nvm.sh: [[: not found
>     /etc/init.d/node_start.sh: 78: root/nvm/nvm.sh: [[: not found
>     /etc/init.d/node_start.sh: 129: root/nvm/nvm.sh: [[: not found
>     /etc/rc.local: 14: /etc/rc.local: source: not found
```

But if i done that command on shell works normally

Any help is welcome

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should add the line below to the end of ~/.bashrc file:

```
[[ -s /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The init script is running as root, not your user. If you want to source your own `nvm.sh`, you shouldn't use `$HOME`, but rather just use the absolute path like `/home/vitor/nvm/nvm.sh`. Also the init script is probably running under `dash` so you should not use the `[[` construct. Just use `[` instead as described in [this dash as /bin/sh article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.5B.5B)

So I went and read the nvm.sh source code from https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/nvm.sh

I don't think that is compatible with dash. So I suggest you leave nvm.sh elsewhere in the filesystem and in your init script just do

```
exec /bin/bash /root/nvm/nvm.sh
```

Starting `node_start.sh` with `#!/bin/bash` may also be sufficient.

You may also want to subscribe to [issue 168 on github for nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/168) where others hit this error.

Comment: Hi tanks for reply, but I follow your advice and keep geting the same error my path is /root/nvm/nvm.sh

Comment: Do you think we'll be able to help you more or less easily if you actually post the source code that is throwing errors?

Answer (score 0):

I expect your init script starts with `#!/bin/sh` when it needs to start with `#!/bin/bash`. Of course, there may be many good reasons not to write init scripts in Bash...